# Showing message after customer is redirected to logout page magento

Tags: magento, session

I have a problem here. I want to show a message to the customer after his/her session is out. Let me explain in detail. I have a case, at first the customer is logged in when the customer clicks the "My Account" he/she is redirected to customer login page.Here i want to show the message that "your session is out please log in again".

One method i tried is to check the customer session in indexAction() in AcountController.php but this redirection is not taking place from this indexAction().

I am guessing that this redirection is taking somewhere from the block because "My Account" link is added through the xml file using "addLink" method.But i couldn't figure it out.

Has anyone faced such problem and has solved it. Can anyone provide me with some insights so i can fix it.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution may be that you can add a script in header.phtml file. In that script you need to check if customer session is set or check customer is logged in or not. On the basis of that on click of 'MY ACCOUNT' button script will check if the customer session is set or not if customer session is not set then show popup message whatever you want to show. This may be a good option.

THANKS